# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting - highlight row to last filled value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a timetable style sheet that has values filled in rows on particular dates. I would like to be able to automatically have the row background colour change up to the last filled value, so you can easily scan down the sheet visually to see longest time since etc.

Image below to illustrate what I mean: the dark backgrounds I have created manually, this is what I would like to auto fill using conditional formatting:

[image: sheets timetable example]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do:

```
=AND(A1 = "", COUNTA(B1:1) > 0)
```

1st condition to color only empty cells, 2nd to color if there's something further.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following under `Custom formula is`

```
=COLUMN(A1)<INDEX(MAX(COLUMN(A1:1)*(--(A1:1<>""))))
```

[image]